# Why mt terraform file provisioner need a connection configuration?

Tags: terraform

I am testing provisioner in Terraform.
This is my sample:

```
resource "null_resource" "demo_provisioner" {
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "C:\\test\\example.txt"
    destination = ".\\example.txt"
  }
}
```

I am just copying a local file to another one, but I get this erreor message:

> Missing connection configuration for provisioner.

I don't understand why this happen. The documentation gives some quite similar example without telling about connection.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check TF docs, it says that [file provisioner](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/file) is about copping files to **remote machine**, which requires a `connection` information to the remote machine.

To copy local files, you can use [local_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) instead.